# Setup Linksys LRT214 t use as my personal vpn to access the nternet from my remote laptop

Tags: networking

I would like to use my home Linksys LRT214 as my personal vpn to access the internet from my remote laptop in a foreign country or other remote location instead of using a VPN service like Express VPN or NORDvpn.

Answer (score 0):

This router VPN Setup is similar to Cisco RVxx VPN routers which I have used.

You need to set up the VPN Router at your residence.

You need a static IP or DynDNS alternative at your residence.

You need client software and setup for your remote device.

Here is a Linksys LRT214 client to site setup document.

[Client to Site VPN Setup](https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article?articleNum=138256)

> ```
> Create a name you want to set for your VPN tunnel in the Tunnel Name field and then select an Interface.
>
> NOTE: By default, the Enable checkbox is already marked. If you need to disable the VPN tunnel you can do so after you create the
> ```
>
> tunnel.
>
> ```
> NOTE: In this example, Tunnel 1 is used as the Tunnel Name and WAN1 is used for Interface. If you have Dual WAN setup, select the
> ```
>
> appropriate WAN interface where the remote client should come in
> through.
>
> ```
> Step 4: In the LOCAL GROUP SETUP section, select the preferred Local Security Gateway Type. Usually IP Only assuming you know the
> ```
>
> external IP address
>
> ```
> IP Only - If users decide to use IP only, entering the IP Address is the only way to gain access to this VPN tunnel. The WAN IP Address
> ```
>
> will be automatically filled into this space. Users don't need to do
> further settings.
>
> ```
> IP + Domain Name (FQDN) Authentication - The WAN IP Address will be automatically filled into this space. Users don't need to do
> ```
>
> further settings. FQDN refers to the combination of host name and
> domain name and can be retrieved from the Internet (i.e.
> vpn.server.com). IP + E-mail Addr. (USER FQDN) Authentication - If
> users select IP Address and E-mail, enter the IP Address and E-mail
> address to gain access to this VPN tunnel and the WAN IP Address will
> be automatically filled into this space. Users don't need to do
> further settings.
>
> ```
> Dynamic IP + Domain Name (FQDN) Authentication - If users use dynamic IP Address to connect to the device, users may select this
> ```
>
> option to link to VPN. If users select this option to link to VPN,
> please enter the domain name. Dynamic IP + E-mail Addr. (USER FQDN)
> Authentication - If users use dynamic IP Address to connect to the
> device, users may select this option to connect to VPN without
> entering IP Address. If users select this option to link to VPN, enter
> E-Mail address to the empty field for E-Mail authentication.
>
> ```
> Select the applicable Local Security Group Type. Usually use Subnet. Be sure to enter the Subnet Mask.
>
> Under REMOTE GROUP SETUP, select the preferred Remote Security Gateway
>
> Type. This needs to match the Client App you use.
>
> Dynamic IP + E-mail Addr. (USER FQDN) Authentication - If remote user uses dynamic IP address to connect to the device, select this
> ```
>
> option and enter the Email address to authenticate the client. This is
> normally the best setup.
>
> ```
> Under IPSEC SETUP, select your Keying Mode. This can either be Manual or IKE with Preshared Key. This is your basic security.
>
> Put in Phase 1 and Phase 2: 3DES , MD5
>
> Enter the Preshared Key.
>
> Now Save.
> ```

For a Client App, LinkSys suggests the Shrewsoft or IPSecuritas Client App.

The client App settings would roughly mirror the settings above.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this when I get home after March 31.

Comment: Pull up the Link as it seems to me quite good and has nice screen shots (not included in the summary above).